# Dataframe Returning Empty - BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently building a dataframe using BeautifulSoup that scrapes data from 1001tracklists.com.

I wrote a script to collect all track information and create a dataframe which worked perfectly when I first finished it and returned the dataframe as expected.

I then modified the script to instead iterate over a list of lists and broke it - now the dataframe returns empty.

I'm not sure where I messed up and can't restore a previous version. I've restarted my kernel several times. I am currently using Jupyter notebook.

My code so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
import urllib.request
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

url_bank = []
url_bank.append(marcel_dettman)
url_bank.append(joy_orbison)

#Marcel_dettman and joy_orbison are 2 lists of urls that I couldn't post here bc they were flagged for spam

djs= []
tracknumbers = []
tracknames = []
artistnames = []
mixnames = []
dates = []
url_scrape = []

for url_list in url_bank:
    for url in url_list:
        count = 0
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Chrome/51.0.2704.103'}
        page_link  = url
        page_response = requests.get(page_link, headers=headers)
        soup = bs(page_response.content, "html.parser")
        title = (page_link[48:-15])
        title = title.replace('-', ' ')
        title = (title[:-1])
        title = title.title()
        title = title.strip('/')
        title = title.strip('K/')
        title = title.strip('1/')
        date = (page_link[-15:-5])

        tracknames_scrape = soup.find_all("div", class_="tlToogleData")
        artistnames_scrape = soup.find_all("meta", itemprop="byArtist")
        for (i, track) in enumerate(tracknames_scrape):
            if track.meta:
                trackname = track.meta['content']
                trackname = trackname.split('- ', 1)[-1]
                tracknames.append(trackname)
                mixnames.append(title)
                dates.append(date)
                djs.append('Joy Orbison')
                url_scrape.append(url)
                count +=1
                tracknumbers.append(count)
            else:
                continue
        for artist in artistnames_scrape:
            artistname = artist["content"]
            artistnames.append(artistname)

df = pd.DataFrame({'DJ Name': djs, 'Date': dates, 'Mix Name': mixnames, 'Track Number': tracknumbers,'Track Name': tracknames, 'Artist Name': artistnames, 'URL':url_scrape})
```

Currently the dataframe returns empty with just headers.
Stackoverflow won't let me post the lists of URLs, so you can see my previous question about a different issue I was having to see what the URLs are like

Comment: this didn't work : /

Comment: Your code works for me. I used only the Joy Orbison URLs from the other post since there were no Marcel Dettman URLs. I made a mock list of lists with `url_bank = [url_list,url_list]`. I got 502 entires back (double the 251 I got with one set) and the headers are nice. Are you possibly hitting the site too much or too often and getting blocked?